# Как из обработчика события dependency property changed в user control'е изменить элемент этого user control'а?

Tags: c#, wpf, usercontrol, dependencyproperty

Я пытаюсь реализовать в юзер контроле нечто вроде toggle button. У нас есть две разные геометрии для использования в качестве двух разных форм для кнопки. Также есть dependency property под названием IsPlaying типа bool. Требуется сделать так, чтобы когда IsPlaying становится true, кнопка начинает использовать геометрию PauseGeometry, а когда false, то PlayGeometry. Как я понимаю, это должно происходить в обработчике Property Changed Callback, но я не понимаю, как добраться из него до кнопки и как назначить ей новую геометрию.
Xaml:

```
<UserControl x:Class="WpfApp5.UserControl1"
             xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
             xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
             xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
             xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"
             d:DesignHeight="450"
             d:DesignWidth="800"
             mc:Ignorable="d">
    <UserControl.Resources>
        <CombinedGeometry x:Key="PlayGeometry"
                          GeometryCombineMode="Exclude">
            <CombinedGeometry.Geometry1>
                <EllipseGeometry Center="25,25"
                                 RadiusX="25"
                                 RadiusY="25" />
            </CombinedGeometry.Geometry1>
            <CombinedGeometry.Geometry2>
                <PathGeometry Figures="M 15,10 L 15,40 L 40,25 Z" />
            </CombinedGeometry.Geometry2>
        </CombinedGeometry>

        <CombinedGeometry x:Key="PauseGeometry"
                          GeometryCombineMode="Exclude">
            <CombinedGeometry.Geometry1>
                <EllipseGeometry Center="25,25"
                                 RadiusX="25"
                                 RadiusY="25" />
            </CombinedGeometry.Geometry1>
            <CombinedGeometry.Geometry2>
                <PathGeometry Figures="M 15,15 L 15,35 L 22.5, 35 L 22.5, 15 Z
                                       M 27.5, 15 L 27.5, 35 L 35, 35 L 35, 15 Z" />
            </CombinedGeometry.Geometry2>
        </CombinedGeometry>
    </UserControl.Resources>
    <Border>
        <Button Click="Button_Click">
            <Button.Template>
                <ControlTemplate TargetType="Button">
                    <Grid>
                        <Path HorizontalAlignment="Center"
                              VerticalAlignment="Center"
                              Data="{StaticResource PlayGeometry}"
                              Fill="Black" />
                    </Grid>
                </ControlTemplate>
            </Button.Template>
        </Button>
    </Border>
</UserControl>
```

Code Behind:

```
using System;
using System.Windows;
using System.Windows.Controls;

namespace WpfApp5;

public partial class UserControl1 : UserControl
{
    public UserControl1()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }

    public bool IsPlaying
    {
        get { return (bool)GetValue(IsPlayingProperty); }
        set { SetValue(IsPlayingProperty, value); }
    }

    public static readonly DependencyProperty IsPlayingProperty =
        DependencyProperty.Register(
            "IsPlaying",
            typeof(bool),
            typeof(UserControl1),
            new PropertyMetadata(false, OnIsPlayingPropertyChanged()));

    static PropertyChangedCallback OnIsPlayingPropertyChanged()
    {
        throw new NotImplementedException();

        //???
    }

    private void Button_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        IsPlaying = !IsPlaying;
    }
}
```

Comment: Не правильно понимаете. У вас есть XAML - инструмент разметки, который создан специально для того, чтобы делать что-то в UI, вот там и делайте это самое "что-то". Вот у вас есть свойство, вам надо на его основе изменить в UI вид, как? А при помощи триггеров, берете `DataTrigger`, привязываете к нужному свойству, на его основе делаете `Setter` нужных UI элементов, готово. И да, вы делаете двойную работу, вам не нужен свой контрол, свое свойство `IsPlaying`, ибо в WPF есть уже готовый контрол, зовется `ToggleButton`, который вам достаточно стилизировать как надо.

Comment: @EvgeniyZ, спасибо за совет. Реализовал то, что мне нужно с помощью триггера, как вы и сказали. А по поводу почему бы не использовать ToggleButton. Мне нужен именно отдельный user control, у которого должно внешнее свойство, которое можно будет использовать. В данном случае использование ToggleButton вместо обычно Button ничего не меняет, насколько я понимаю.

Comment: `<ToggleButton IsChecked = "true"/>` против `<namespace:UserControl1 IsPlaying = "true"/>`, разницу видите (кроме названий)? Я нет. Вы пишете тот-же самый функционал, который уже и так существует в готовом решении, в котором вам достаточно лишь поменять стиль на тот, который вы хотите.

Comment: @EvgeniyZ, хотелось бы иметь готовый user contol, который можно использовать как есть в разных приложениях и не писать каждый раз код для стиля. Да и понимать, как можно сделать тот или иной готовый элемент никогда не будет лишним.

Comment: Стиль выносите в отдельный ресурс, и пишете `<ToggleButton Style = "{StaticResource Name}"/>`, готово. Если лень постоянно писать, то создайте стиль без указания `Key`, будет применен на все `ToggleButton` в проекте. Ну ок, хотите свой, унаследуйте от `ToggleButton`, напишите ему стиль без `Key`, используйте `<nameSpace:Control IsChecked = "..." />`, будет то, что хотите. Вариантов как видите уйма, просто зачем повторять функционал который уже существует, я не знаю) Но дело ваше, хотите свой, делайте)